# MySQL in RHEL shows different versions

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.1

I was given a RHEL 6.9 server with MySQL installed and I just wanted to check the MySQL version running on it.

When I tried the `rpm -qa | grep mysql` or `mysql --version` or `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` commands they show the version as 5.6.36

However when I run `yum info mysql-server` it shows a different version (5.1.73) than the other commands.

What could be the reason for this.

Comment: I referred this post https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tell-version-mysql-unix-linux-command/ to check the version.

Answer (score 0):

The command `rpm -qa` shows what is installed. If it does not give what you look for then it is not installed with `yum`.